# Is Azure subscription needed for MSTeams Bot creation

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

With the move of Microsoft to disable the App Registration on the legacy portal we created the Bot for our MSTeams APP in Azure portal that is part of the 'Renewable E5 subscription'.But we could not able to set the Bot messaging end point url. Earlier we can able to set that from the MSTeams' App Studio's Bot section but now it is not there.  https://dev.botframework.com/ asks us to create a Azure Bot service.

1. Is it necessary to create a Azure Bot service in order to use and set the Bot message End point ?
2. If not how can we set the Bot messaging End point without Azure Bot service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem, now that the functionality is removed from App Studio, that you need to work in the Azure Portal directly (that's all it was doing behind the scenes). This would require an Azure subscription, but you can use any one, so you don't necessarily require an Azure subscription for each team member.

It is important to note though, that the only thing you really need in Azure is a bot "registration". There are two options when creating a bot resource in Azure - one includes a full hosting option ("web app bot"), and associated costs (based on the options selected), and the other is just a "channel registration", which has no cost at all.

When the bot is created, you need to go to it's "Settings" screen, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-settings?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), where you set the messaging endpoint, but you also need to make sure to go to the "Channels" option on the left menu, and make sure Teams is added as a channel ("channel" here means a platform you want to use your bot on, like Teams, facebook, slack etc.). If your bot had been created in App Studio previously, it would not need the Teams channel added manually, but for new bots it will.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need azure subscription. Now you can not create bot from botframework.com. Everything is moved to Azure.